# bitbucket: untracked folder?

Tags: git, bitbucket

[image: what's that unusual folder (marked in red)?]

what's that unusual folder (marked in red)?
It seems to be an untracked folder.
I tried to manually adding the file with:

```
git add folder/untracked_folder
```

but it does not seem to change anything.

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**That is a `submodule`.**

Repositories with submodules when cloned without `--recursive` option creates empty directories for submodules. Either you clone using,

```
git clone <repo-url> --recursive
```

or use,

```
git submodule update --init
```

Comment: Great, but how do i change it to not be a submodule? I had deleted a .git folder, in the folder in question.

Comment: The directory has an entry in the `.gitmodules` file. If you want to delete it. Follow the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/1587370)

Comment: I had deleted the .gitmodules folder, to solve the issue, before askeing in here.